# Is there any way of adding shortcut keys for MenuBar/MenuItem elements in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to add keyboard shortcuts to a GWT menu, same as in most windows applications (for example <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>O</kbd> -> activates the "File" menu, then "Open" MenuItem ).

I know it may conflict with browser shortcuts, so I'm interested in a way of disabling those too...

From what I can see google has all kinds of shortcuts in their applications so, there must be a way to do this.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Thanks to Igor's response I'm able to capture keyboard input before being consumed by other controls.

What I don't know is how to make the MenuBar show itself (like when mouse hovering). MenuBar doesn't seem to have a method .open() :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but [`NativeEvent`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html) seems to be what you are looking for. You get to it via [`Event.addNativePreviewHandler(Event.NativePreviewHandler)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.html#addNativePreviewHandler(com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler)):

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event) {
        nativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
        // Do all sort of cool stuff with nativeEvent
    }
});
```

Reference: [GWT Google Group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/cba5c3aea017fa59/3b8dfaf31fa1ca19)

---

To select a menu item programatically, use [`MenuBar.selectItem(MenuItem item)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html#selectItem(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuItem)) - you'll probably need to keep track of the relevant `MenuItem`s. From the selected `MenuItem` you can get to its sub menu via [`MenuItem.getSubMenu()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuItem.html#getSubMenu()) and so on... :) You can play around with the auto-open setting ([`MenuBar.setAutoOpen(boolean autoOpen)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html#setAutoOpen(boolean)) to get it to work like you envisioned.

Comment: Thank you, this points me in the right direction. Seems to work fine on Firefox, but as usual IE is a bitch again. Doesn't fire events for "special" keys (like ALT, CTRL).

Comment: You mean, when *only* Alt is pressed? For combinations with other keys, `getAltKey()` should work.

Comment: No. In IE, ALT + i or CTRL + i doesn't work. Just "i" works, however. For what I need right now I can live with a direct shortcut (without Alt, or Ctrl).

Comment: No event is generated when you press Ctrl + i? If so, this warrants a bug report (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list) :)

Comment: Hmm... I tried with selectItem, and indeed it selects the passed item, but the menu doesn't open (I only see the parent menuItem highlighted). Tried with  setAutoOpen true or false, no change.

Comment: How about the submenu - does it have auto-open enabled? Because, the way I see it, that's what you want to open when you select the item (MenuBar1 -> MenuItem -> MenuBar2, MenuBar1 is always showing, it's the top menu bar, MenuBar2 is shown when MenuItem is selected). So, MenuBar2 should have auto-open enabled. Unfortunately, I can't test this right now :/

Comment: Tried this; no change :(

I'm thinking of a different approach. Is is possible to simulate a mouse over event? If I could send a fake mouse over event to the menuBar it should work... But I have no idea on how to do that

Comment: `MenuBar.fireEvent` with the appropriate event or maybe `DomEvent.fireNativeEvent` (but I don't know where you'd get a `NativeEvent` from). You could create a new question, if this didn't help (or maybe check if there's a related question on SO, I think there was...).

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'll look into this some more.